# Cheque book designer in WinForm

Tags: winforms, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to create a cheque book designer similar to the image attached. I am unable to find the suitable control. Can anyone suggest how can I implement similar tool?[Cheque Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAndk.jpg)

Comment: The attached image contains multiple controls, are you referring to a specific one?  The main cheque part looks like it uses the selected image as the background and arranges some textboxes/labels according to the selected template.

Comment: Concept is that the user will add their sample cheque and place the align the text-boxes accordingly. Once they submit, we will get the left, top and width of the controls and create a run-time report based on the values. I am not sure how can I achieve this objective.

Comment: You should probably do a form similar to the design in your image and let the user enter the information. Once it's done, generate a report with the information from the user. Look at .rdlc report [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-rdlc-report-in-C-Sharp-Asp-Net/) and [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/RDLC-Report-in-C-b106fc20)